# Autoform users profile page

Tags: meteor

I try create user profile page with autoform, but autorofm tell me **"Error: AutoForm: You must specify a collection when form type is insert."**

I have only one way through the methods?

Please help me to solve the problem.

*Helper*
`Template.accountForm.helpers({
    userSchema: function () {
        return Schema.User;
    }
});`

*Template*
`<template name="accountForm">
    <div class="panel-body">
        {{#autoForm schema=userSchema collection=Users id="accountForm" type="insert"}}
        <fieldset>
             {{> afObjectField name='profile'}}
        </fieldset>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Insert</button>
        {{/autoForm}}
    </div>
</template>`

*Schema*

```
Schema = {};

Schema.UserProfile = new SimpleSchema({
    lastname: {
        type: String
    }
});

Schema.User = new SimpleSchema({
    _id: {
        type: String,
        regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Id
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date
    },
    profile: {
        type: Schema.UserProfile,
    },
    services: {
        type: Object,
        optional: true,
        blackbox: false
    }
});

Meteor.users.attachSchema(Schema.User);
```

Comment: Change your auto form tag to use `type="update"`. That should fix it.

Comment: Tnx for answer but no, not working

Comment: Yes, again "Error: AutoForm: You must specify a collection when form type is insert."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the helper function, just use the `Meteor.users` object.

```
{{#autoForm collection='Meteor.users' doc=currentUser type='update' id='accountForm'}}
  {{> afQuickField name='profile'}}
<button type='submit' class="btn btn-primary">Save profile</button>
{{/autoForm}}
```

Comment: shouldn't that be `afObjectField`?